# DataView losing Sort order

Tags: c#, sorting

I am having a bit of issue with DataView.Sort. When it is binded to the pageddatasource it lose the sort order?

By default the data is sorted by Date in Descending order.

Here is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    ViewState["Column"] = "OrderDate";
    ViewState["Order"] = "ASC";

    PopulateProductClass();
    PopulateProduct(); 
  }
  PopulateOrderList();
 }

private void PopulateOrderList()
{
  DateTime d;
  DateTime d2;

  CustomerInfo ki = CustomerInfoProvider.GetCustomerInfoByUserID(CooneenHelper.GetUserImpersonisationID());
  int nKustomerID = ki.CustomerID;
  DataTable dts = new DataTable();
  dts.Columns.Add("OrderDate", typeof(string));
  dts.Columns.Add("OrderNumber", typeof(string));
  dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemSKUName", typeof(string));
  dts.Columns.Add("SKUNumber", typeof(string));
  dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemStatus", typeof(string));
  dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemUnitCount", typeof(string));

  QueryDataParameters qdp = new QueryDataParameters();
  qdp.Add("@CustomerID", nKustomerID);

  if (drpProductClass.HasControls())
  {
    if (drpProductClass.SelectedValue.ToString() != "0" || drpProductClass.SelectedValue.ToString() == null) { qdp.Add("@OrderItemWRClass", drpProductClass.SelectedItem.ToString()); }
    if (drpProduct.SelectedValue.ToString() != "0") { qdp.Add("@OrderItemSKUID", drpProduct.SelectedValue.ToString()); }
  }           

  if (txtStartDate.Text != "") { d = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text); qdp.Add("@OrderItemDateFrom", d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); }
  if (txtEndDate.Text != "") { d2 = DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text); qdp.Add("@OrderItemDateTo", d2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); }

  DataSet ds = gc.ExecuteQuery("CN_GetOrderItemByCustID", qdp, QueryTypeEnum.StoredProcedure, true);
  foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
  {
    DataRow drNew = dts.NewRow();
    drNew["OrderDate"] = ValidationHelper.GetDateTime(dr["OrderDate"], DateTime.Now).ToShortDateString();
    drNew["OrderNumber"] = dr["OrderNumber"].ToString();
    drNew["OrderItemSKUName"] = dr["OrderItemSKUName"].ToString();
    drNew["SKUNumber"] = dr["SKUNumber"].ToString();
    drNew["OrderItemStatus"] = dr["OrderItemStatus"].ToString();
    drNew["OrderItemUnitCount"] = dr["OrderItemUnitCount"].ToString();      
    dts.Rows.Add(drNew);
  }

  //Clear the TextBox
  litResults.Text = String.Empty;

  if (dts.Rows.Count == 1)
    litResults.Text = "" + dts.Rows.Count.ToString() + " Order Items";
  else
    litResults.Text = "" + dts.Rows.Count.ToString() + " Order Items";


  PagedDataSource pds = new PagedDataSource();
  DataView view = dts.DefaultView;
  view.Sort = ViewState["Column"].ToString() + " " + ViewState["Order"].ToString();

  pds.DataSource = view;


  //allow paging, set page size, and current page
  pds.AllowPaging = true;
  pds.PageSize = PerPage;
  pds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;

  //show # of current page in label
  if (pds.PageCount > 1) litResults.Text += " - Showing page " + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " of " + pds.PageCount.ToString();

  //disable prev/next buttons on the first/last pages
  btnPrev.Enabled = !pds.IsFirstPage;
  btnNext.Enabled = !pds.IsLastPage;

  rprOrders.Visible = true;

  rprOrders.DataSource = pds;
  rprOrders.DataBind();

}
```

When the data is returned from the database into DataTable `dts` the sorting is fine. However when it is sorted using the DataView it seems to lose its sorting order?

```
PagedDataSource pds = new PagedDataSource();
DataView view = dts.DefaultView;
view.Sort = ViewState["Column"].ToString() + " " +     ViewState["Order"].ToString();
//Sorting order lost in view
pds.DataSource = view;
```

I am not sure exactly how?

Comment: 1) Have you checked the view after assigning to PagedDataSource? Is sorting the same before and after assignment? 2) Do you have correct values for sorting in the ViewState? Maybe somehow they get erased.

Comment: At this point `DataView view = dts.DefaultView;` data is still in ordered list from when the data has been fetched back from dB. However it the order is lost at `pds.DataSource = view`

Comment: Checked further and it seems `view.Sort = ViewState["Column"].ToString() + " " + ViewState["Order"].ToString();` is upsetting the order?
Both `ViewState["Order"] and ViewState["Column"]` have data inside them

Comment: Try to create a view in this way: `DataView view = new DataView(dts);`. Is sorting still erased?

Comment: Yep still erasing :(

Comment: Can you create a simple demonstrative example so I could run it on my local machine?

Comment: I have been following this tutorial http://shravanti88.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/sorting-in-repeater.html Perhaps you can see if the dataview sort works for you? thanks